# How to write ohm symbol in the legend section of Sigmaplot

Tags: sigmaplot

How to write ohm symbol in the legend section of Sigmaplot? I didn't find this symbol in symbol section of Sigmaplot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking for the `greek capital letter omega`. That's where the ohm symbol comes from.

> Ω DEC-937 HEX-03A9    Ω GREEK CAPITAL LETTER OMEGA